# Need help identifying shower diverter cartridge

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

Shower diverter:
[image]
[image]

Need help identifying shower diverter cartridge for replacement

Comment: Do you know he name of the manufacturer?

Comment: i thinks its kohler but not positive

Comment: the piece thats broken is the plastic connector between the diverter and the pull handle.  i am planning to replace the whole cartridge but i  want to keep the pull

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be difficult identifying that part without a model number. At this point I think your best bet would be to go to your local home store and search the plumbing section racks for an identical part. Better yet, take it to a plumbing supply store and they'll be able to match it. Good luck.

Comment: thanks,  i found the diverter replacement part!  thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

tempress II diverter old style

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.